# Should a bounty prevent a question from being closed

Tags: feature-request, bounty, vote-to-close

This [question](https://superuser.com/questions/542089/how-to-install-multiple-microsoft-applications-without-conflicts) should be closed as not constructive or too localized.  Yet it cant be voted closed, since it has an active bounty.

Shouldnt close votes take priority?

Comment: Relevant: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14591/how-can-we-close-questions-with-bounties

Comment: FWIW, I don't see a compelling reason to close the question. Can it not be answered with specific expertise?

Answer (score 3):

Like mentioned in the MSO Oliver linked:

[How can we close questions with bounties?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14591/how-can-we-close-questions-with-bounties)

Flag the question for moderator attention, we can remove the bounty and then close the question.

Answer (score 2):

I feel this should be allowed, because I've run into questions that had bounties but should be closed, often for being not constructive or not a real question.  However, I feel it should take eight votes (more or less) to close a question with a bounty, rather than the normal five.  Users should be advised to exercise caution when voting to close a question with a bounty, since closure would automatically end the bounty.

If possible, one-half of the bounty should be awarded automatically to the highest-scoring answer posted since the bounty was started with a score of at least +2, as if the bounty had expired.  Otherwise, the bounty would be lost.